# Reject a transition based on user input, without confirm()

Tags: ember.js

[EmberJS: reject an upcoming transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104374/emberjs-reject-an-upcoming-transition)

How would I reject an upcoming transition via willTransition, but using a custom pop up or jQuery .dialog box such as this:

```
willTransition: function(transition) {
    //Some conditional logic would go here to determine if they need to be prompted to save
    $("#confirmTransition").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                self.transitionTo(transition.targetName);
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "No": function() {
                transition.abort();
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Rather than using confirm() which would actually wait until the user enters something. I can use a .then, but it fires after the transition completes. Would I be better off using beforeModel on all routes to handle a conditional abort, and then rely on willTransition to provide the popup to confirm?

**Updated per accepted question:**

```
willTransition: function(transition) {
    //Some conditional logic would go here to determine if they need to be prompted to save
    var self = this;
    if(!self._transitioning){
        $("#confirmTransition").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            buttons: {
                "Yes": function() {
                    self._transitioning = true;
                    transition.retry().then(self._transitioning = false);
                    $(this).dialog( "close" );
                },
                "No": function() {
                    transition.abort();
                    $(this).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the same approach to animate route transitions: You can take a look at [the relatebase blog](http://blog.relatabase.com/ember-animated-routes) (as well as the [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/2106/edit) referred by the blog).

Essentially you handle a little state machine in the `willTransition` action: You abort the original transition and as soon as the user closes the dialog you retry the original transition.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Fabulous! I tried the whole abort() and retry() before, but it would abort the retry as well. So toggling a state machine value like _transitioning between calls is exactly what I needed. I catch it if it's false, prompt the user, and set it to true and retry if they click "yes". Perfect solution. Thanks!

Comment: Updated the original question with the solution per your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: For future readers, a guide on how to do this with Ember components is here:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/